# Get website user time and timezone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does rails provide solution to get website user time and timezone configured on his local machine, which is used in his web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails (Ruby actually) is a **server-side language**, so to retrieve data about the client side you would need to use JavaScript:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var zone = -(currentTime.getTimezoneOffset() / 60); //GMT
```

Comment: You haven't understand me. Time class returns time on the server machine. I want to get current time on clinet machine which browser the website.

Comment: that looks like would work but what if the user had javascript turned off?

Comment: @DJTripleThreat, then there would be no way of doing it.

Comment: I thought that localtime could be extracted from request headers.